# How to create a custom validation rule in cake 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am working on Cake 3. I want to create a custom validation-rule.
I want to check if the field 'password' is equal to the 'confirm_password' field.

This is my code:

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
        $validator
                ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
                ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
                ->add('email', 'valid', ['rule' => 'email'])
                ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('email')
                ->add('email', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table'])
                ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('password')
                ->notEmpty('confirm_password')
                ->add('confirm_password', 'custom', [
                    'rule' => function($value, $context) {
                        if ($value !== $context['data']['password']) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return false;
                    },
                    'message' => 'The passwords are not equal',
        ]);

        return $validator;
    }
```

When I try to 'fail' the form-submit, the code saves, and I get no error.

I read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules but didn't help.... Anybody?

Thanks!

Comment: not for me :P what did you do; exactly copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I've found it on myself. To everybody who stuck on cake's models: NEVER FORGET TO ADD YOUR FIELDS TO THE `$_accessible`-array IN YOUR ENTITY!

My code:

```
    /UsersTable.php;

    $validator->add('confirm_password', 'custom', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            return false; // Its ment to go wrong ;)
        },
        'message' => 'Password not equal',
    ]);

    /User.php;

    protected $_accessible = [
        'email'            => true,
        'password'         => true,
        'bookmarks'        => true,
        'role_id'          => true,
        'confirm_password' => true,
    ];
```

Comment: This is just wrong. The _accessible property will just allow mass assignment to the properties given. I suggest you remove the accepted answer for other users coming here.

Answer (score 18):

Another built in way to compare two passwords with CakePHP 3 validation could be:

```
->add('confirm_password',
    'compareWith', [
        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
        'message' => 'Passwords not equal.'
    ]
)
```

You can also add this to your `validationDefault` method in your Table definition.

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this code ,it will work for sure**

```
 $validator
     ->notEmpty('cpassword')
     ->add('cpassword', ['length' => ['rule' => ['minLength', 8],'message' => 'Password need to be at least 8 characters long',]])
     ->add('cpassword', 'passwordsEqual', [
                'rule' => function($value, $context) {
                    return isset($context['data']['cpassword']) &&
                     $context['data']['password'] === $value;      
                },
                'message' => 'The two password you typed do not match.',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function validationResetpassword(Validator $validator){
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('password')
        ->notEmpty('password','Please enter Password')
        ->add('confirm_password', [
                    'compare' => [
                    'rule' => ['compareWith','password'],
                    'message' => 'Confirm Password does not match with Password.'
                    ]])
                    ->requirePresence('confirm_password')
                    ->notEmpty('confirm_password','Please enter Confirm Password')
                    ;

    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: where is `compareWith` method i this someting is missing in  your code